# Contenteditable automatically detection of RTL text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Does anyone knows a way to, as the user inputs text on a contenteditable what's that text directionality, LTR or RTL?

Until now I've been using the [RTLtextarea](https://github.com/twitter/RTLtextarea) from twitter and it works perfectly on textarea elements (as it is supposed to), but now I need a solution to do the same on a contenteditable div.

I want it to work like twitter tweet box, that is a contenteditable and automatically detects RTL text.